# Inserting multiple values from Checkbox into 4 Columns

Tags: php

I'm a little confused here. I want to add 4 values to the db. Exept if the user only add < 4.

DB columns are:

```
ticket1, ticket2, ticket3, ticket4
```

There are multiple checkboxes 1-19.

```
<input class='' id='cbx' value='1' name='check_num[]' type='checkbox'/><label>1</label>
```

My code is...

```
 if(!empty($_POST['check_num'])) {

     foreach($_POST['check_num'] as $key => $value) {

          //i just need the ARRAY or something to divide the numbers in peaces to put on the db.

     }
 } else {
   echo "empty"; 
 }
```

Comment: I'd look at the sizeof() or count() functions. I assume this is a school assignment?

Comment: yes it is. I just want get all the NUMBERS from checkboxes and put them into the COLUMNS separatly. @TCooper

Comment: Can you give me a suggest or something.

Comment: But only if less than 4 are checked? What happens if more than 4 are checked?

Comment: Cannot be more than 4. (I need to do a IF after i finish this part. The user should only add 1-4 checkboxes

Comment: See the posted answer, but can't help any more without knowing about your database choices

Comment: as a sidenote, you might ought to check out database normalisation as well. instead of putting checkbox 1, 2, 3 ,4 in columns, put it in a separate table instead and ticket number and user id on each row instead.

Comment: is how it is. USER_ID and Tickets.. but for what i need it is necessary to have 4 ticket numbers separated. @Kevin

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like this, but there are plenty of alternatives.

```
if(!empty($_POST['check_num'])) {
    $count = count($_POST['check_num']);
    if($count <= 4){
        $columns = "";
        $values = "";
        $i = 1;
        while($i <= $count){
            $columns .= "ticket".$i.", ";
            $params .= "?, ";
            $types .= "i";
            $i++;
        }
        $columns = substr($columns, 0, 2);
        $params = substr($columns, 0, 2);
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO [table_name] (".$columns.") VALUES (".$params.");";);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $types, ...$_POST['check_num']);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
    else{
        echo "Too many selections";
    }
}
else{
    echo "empty"; 
}
```

I haven't used anything but PDO for prepared in php in several years. Might be my bias but I'd recommend the switch, this seemed more complicated to me. **You may need to update the portions using mysqli prepare and bind** I haven't tested this code at all, just wrote it in the answer.

I also assumed each column was an integer type, and of course, update to use your table name in the query.

I added the `substr()` functions to remove trailing `", "` from last entry of each, you could also check if `$i == $count` before those assignments, and use a different assignment set without the trailing `", "` inside that `if()` with the current assignments in the following `else`. The `$i++` would obviously be outside this `if()/else`.

Comment: That part it's ok.. i just want to add like INSERT (ticket1, ticket2, ticket3, ticket4) VALUES($value1, $value2, $value3, $value4), this is what i want. Every Number from Checkbox INSERTED.

Comment: But what DB are you using? What library/methods are you using to interact with it?

Comment: PHPMYADMIN MYSQLI, to protect the POSTS i'm only using mysqli_real_escape_string($con, sanitize())

Comment: Got it, for future reference/real world applications, please read this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391315/is-mysqli-real-escape-string-enough-to-avoid-sql-injection-or-other-sql-attack - but I'll update the answer now.

Comment: and i use MYSQLI prepared Statments (?)

Comment: Got it, that's what you need. There's a few ways to handle this, I'd check for the existence of a value and if it doesn't exist set it to an empty string for simplicity, then run one query to update. I assume you also have a user id or similar unique identifier to know which row to insert these values to?

Comment: yes, i use user_id => INT, i think at the moment i just need to figure out how to ADD the 4 checkbox into 4 COLUMNS like 1,2,3,4

Comment: @MarianaSilva see updated answer, you'll still need to test, and maybe tweak yourself, but should get you the concepts.